# Add Jquery datepicker to other script how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

Good day people. I'm very new in JavaScript and JQuery and I have question.Guys how can put too scripts together????  I have a datepicker script:

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["ru"]);



 $("#dateinput").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
                        showOn: 'both',
                        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                        },
                        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                        }

                    });
```

And I have another script actually script as plugin, this script let me use input and select together, so if user can't find something from list he can put his own data, his just piace from my web page:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
                                console.log($('.widthclass').select2_e().on('change', function () {
                                    alert(this.value);

                                }));
                            });              
                    });
```

And code inside of the plugin because as I said I use it like plugin:

```
//Plugin initialization
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.select2_e = function () {
        $(this).each(function (n, element) {
            //тут превращаем select в input              
            var $element = $(element),
                choices = $element.find('option').map(function (n, e) {
                    var $e = $(e);
                    return {
                        id: $e.val(),
                        text: $e.text()
                    };
                }),
                width = $element.width(),
                $input = $('<input>', {
                    width: width
                });
            $element.hide().after($input);
            //make select form input

            $input.select2({
                query: function (query) {
                    var data = {}, i;
                    data.results = [];

                    // add what we searched for

                    if (query.term !== "") {
                        data.results.push({
                            id: query.term,
                            text: query.term
                        });
                    }

                    // add other

                    for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                        if (choices[i].text.match(query.term) || choices[i].id.match(query.term)) data.results.push(choices[i]);
                    }

                    query.callback(data);
                }
            }).on('change', function () {
                var value = $input.val();
                $element.empty();
                $element.append($('<option>').val(value));
                $element.val(value).trigger('change');
            });;
            return $element;
        });
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And my jsp all together how it looks:

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title><spring:message code="label.input.head" var="headTitle"/></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/select2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/select2.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/select2_e.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/inputStyle.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jsFiles/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/cssFiles/jquery-ui.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {  

                     $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["ru"]);

                     $("#dateinput").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
                            showOn: 'both',
                            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                            },
                            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                            }

                        });

                        function beforeShowDayHandler(date) {
                            if (self.SelectedDayValue != -1) {
                                if (date.getDate() != 1) {
                                    return [false, '', 'selected'];
                                }
                            }
                            return [true, ''];
                        }

                         jQuery(function ($) {
                                console.log($('.widthclass').select2_e().on('change', function () {
                                    alert(this.value);

                                }));
                            });              
                    }); 
             </script>

    </head>


    <body>

        <spring:message code="label.input.button" var="save"/>

        <table align="left">
            <tr> <td> Language/Язык/文 : <a href="input?lang=en">English</a>||<a href="input?lang=ru">Русский</a>||<a href="input?lang=cn">中文</a> </td> </tr>
        </table>

        <table align="right">
            <tr> <td> <button style="background-color: #E0E0E0; vertical-align: middle; border: thin;"> <img src="resources/log_out.png" alt="logout_logo" align="center" /> <a href="j_spring_security_logout"> <spring:message code="label.login.logout"/> </a> </button> </td> </tr>
        </table>

        <br/>

        <table align="center">
            <tr><td width="620"> <h3 align="left"> <select cssClass="widthclass"> <form:option value=""/> <options items="${listOfDates}"/> </select> </td></tr>
        </table>    

     <form action="add" method="post">  

        <table align="center"  style="border-bottom-style:inset; border-top-style: outset;">

        <tr><td align="right"> <input id=" </td> </tr>
```

So I need to to put them together when user click on input field it open select and datepicker. Than you

Comment: hey, can you paste your code in jsfiddle.net, too much at first, to understand

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Sam. Sorry, yes I can. This is my one peace of script http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x4XQp/10/ to this script I need add datepicker. Please help. Thank you Sam

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i could not understand your full requirement, but may be you are looking for just integrate the datepicker with this script.

Well i have did the change, hope you are looking for this.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                       // beforeShowDay: beforeShowDayHandler,
                        showOn: 'both',
                        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                        },
                        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                        }

                    });

    console.log($('.testclass').select2_e().on('change', function () {
        alert(this.value)
    }));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4XQp/12/)

If have to use jquery.ui plugin. may be that was the error in your try.

Comment: Yes sir, thank you for reply. I want to integrate datapicker with this script, but I want to put it inside but not make suppurate field. I'm sorry for my insistence.